# Error emrfs create-metadata not working on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-iam, amazon-emr

While performing **emrfs create-metadata** operation on emr master node I am getting the following error

```
Error creating meatadata EmrFSMetadata: User: arn:aws:sts::<accountid>:assumed-role/emr-ec2-role/i-04dlcd547ef60654a is not authorized to perform: 
dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:<account id >:/table/EmrFSMetadata (Service: AmazonDynamoDB2; 
Status code: 400: Error code: AccessdeniedException;
```

IAM `emr-ec2-role` has has `dynamodb:DescribeTable permission.`

still I am getting error.

pleaes help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

It's resolve 
VPC endpoint was blocking it

I add **EmrFSMetadata** table name in Dynamodb VCP endpoint policy and given **create table** permission.

Answer (score 0):

I use AWS managed policy in `emr-ec2-role`. I don’t have any problem these.

Have you checked if you have any resource limitation in `emr-ec2-role` -

Lets say you have this permission

```
{
    "Action": [
        "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:<a-different-region>::/table/*"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Sid": "VisualEditor1"
}
```

So the table that you are accessing is on `us-east-1`. And you actually have permission to describe table on other region.

If that doesn’t help either, try use AWS managed policy for once
`arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role` and see if there is any error.

Comment: In resources I have given *

Comment: Can you check, if making the action `dynamodb:*`, see if dynamodb:DescribeTable has other dependency.

Comment: if you can read the error carefully, then it seams like User is not able access it

Comment: User: arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role/emr-ec2-role/i-04dlcd547ef60654a

Comment: Are you able to access any service using that role? Please check other services like s3. Im just trying to understand the problem.